# Place buttons in LinearLayout Vertical and Horizantal

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

I am new with Android programming and using latest version of Android Studio.

I have a `LinearLayout` and want to put 20 buttons programmatically.

```
LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linear_layout);
linearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
for (int i = 0; i<20;i++)
{
  Button btn = new Button(this);
  btn.setText("Button" + (i + 1));
  btn.setTag(i + 1);
  btn.setLayoutParams (new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(200, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,1));
  btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View view) {
         Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), view.getTag().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
           }
        });
        linearLayout.addView(btn);
 }
```

I am using this code. It adds 20 buttons one under the other. However I want to place them like this:

```
Button1 Button2
Button3 Button4
...
Button19 Button20
```

Is it possible with `LinearLayout` or should i use different type of layout?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do this with just one LinearLayout.

To achieve this you must either use:

[TableLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableLayout.html), [GridView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridView.html), or (not ideal compared to these two) 2 Vertical LinearLayouts inside a Horizontal LinearLayout

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have used TableLayout and it worked but I would like to know which one is better to use for this purpose? Does GridView have an advantage?

Comment: You're welcome glad it helped you. Depends, they serve for different purposes. With TableLayout, you can have more customisable and different types inside it, in GridView, you use an adapter which you can't really customise as easy as you can do with TableRows.

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible using single LinearLayout. You can use nested layouts so in your example Button1 and Button2 are in one horizontal layout and that layout is then added to larger vertical layout.

You can also use GridLayout - it was designed to handle your case easily.